# Chrome pop-up "Open With..." how to remember choice?

Tags: google-chrome

[image]

Couple versions ago there was a checkbox 'Always open such files with this app'
Now this checkbox is absent
Does anybody know how to remember choice now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Chrome 77? Than you are not the only one with this problem.
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/14194567?hl=en

[image: Chrome76-vs-77]

> This is intended The "always open these types of links in the
>   associated app" checkbox is missing because the devs discussed that it
>   wasn't right as there is no option to undo such a choice.   Can't make
>   it better than that. Sorry, I'm just here to give you information.

So it looks like for now, you don't really have an option. The removed this option because you they say: once remembed, you can't undo that choice. So it's completely deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution I didn't see anywhere else, if a specific site/ program is the issue as in my case. 
Delete Chrome from your machine, install an old version (I used 62) go to the site, check the box then update. 
Chrome will remember your preference.